# PhpStorm - launching debug doesn't work

Tags: phpstorm

Trying to debug a PHP Web Application makes my browser request this URL:
    file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/JetBrains/PhpStorm%20146/jre/jre/bin/127.0.0.1/get.php%3FXDEBUG_SESSION_START=17425

The Start URL is this: 127.0.0.1/get.php.

The PhpStorm version i'm running is 2016.1. There is no PhpStorm 146 in that folder (but what is it requesting it then?)

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Your settings are screw up -- either you did them like that or something else -- I do not know. The URL it tires to launch is VERY odd. I would suggest few things: 1) Go trough all your settings (`File | Settings`) and look for that stuff; once found -- post screenshots here; Also check your existing Run/Debug Configurations 2) just close IDE; go to the project folder and delete `.idea ` subfolder -- this project settings; then open IDE again and using `Open` action point to project root -- IDE will create brand new project from existing files;

Comment: 3) Close IDE and delete ALL IDE-wide settings (you may back them up in advance) ; When launched again -- do not import anything -- start from scratch - https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: This particular configuration (for an old workspace) was created a long time ago, but I'd like to just edit IT, not all the others I have.. :(

Comment: So .. do point #1. Right now I cannot say for sure where that path comes from .. as such path should NEVER be used for web URL (that's why I've used word "screw up" for setting. So -- check your existing Run/Debug Configurations first; Then check your "PHP | Servers" definitions; Deployment entries...